# Webview Back button while loading url

Tags: android, progress-bar, back-button

So i'm attempting to load a url after i click a record in a list view, and open a new activity. All works great... except while the `progressBar` is showing the back button is disabled. I'd like to enable it so it can do a `finish()`

```
private void loadWebView(String url) {      
    WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(OtherDetailActivity.this, "Please Wait", "Loading Website...");

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.i(Utils.TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e(Utils.TAG, "Error: " + description);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OtherDetailActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Error")
            .setMessage(description)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
    web.loadUrl(url);

}
```

Comment: Just don't understand your question.What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Like @Libin said, i can `progressBar.setCancelable(true);` to enable me to cancel the progress bar but now on canceling it i want the activity to `finish()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `ProgressDialog` as cancelable (true) .

```
progressBar.setCancelable(true);
```

`setCancelable` sets whether this dialog is cancelable with the `BACK` key

If you need to close the `Activity` when the `Progress dialog dismiss` on `BACK` key, add a listener like this and `finish` the `Activity`.

```
  progressBar.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Since `OnDismissListener` will get invoked in general on all dialog `dismiss` conditions , you can  set `OnCancelListener` which only be invoked only when the dialog is `cancelled`

```
 progressBar.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well that was simple enough, why didn't I think of that... I've been looking at this too long. The back button cancels the dialog not but doesn't close the activity. How can i force a close when it is canceled?

Comment: Your no longer my hero ;) When the webview finishes loading and closes it does the finish from the above code!